# Polymer core-pages no height

Tags: html, css, polymer

I'm trying to create my first project with Polymer. I use `core-pages` to navigate between different pages. These pages should have a white `background-color` in css, but there is no on the site.

Here is a link:  http://www.test.gruppenstunde.eu/

The problem is, that `core-pages` and my custom element `modules-list` don't have a fixed height, because that changes with the content. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `<modules-list>` is styled with `position: absolute`. Switching to `position: relative` should accomplish what you're looking for—the white background color will show up. Below is an example of the change made via Chrome's DevTools, illustrating what it will look like:

[image: Screenshot showing position: relative]

I've found myself needing to brush up on CSS positioning quite a bit in order to work effectively with Polymer, since there are a number of `<core-*>` elements that effectively don't have any default positioning/sizing info, requiring developers to make the appropriate decisions for their apps. I've found [this guide](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) particularly useful, but there are plenty of other good resources out there.

Comment: Tank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works when using vanilla `core-pages` and children with `class="core-selected"`

```
core-pages .core-selected {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Found more help here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/HrsXUjni2kA